# Linear funnel from a collection of events with MongoDB aggregation, is it possible?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, report, aggregation-framework

I have a number of event documents, each event has a number of fields, but the ones that are relevant for my query are:

- person_id - a reference to the person that triggered the event
- event - a string key to identify the event
- occurred_at - the utc of the time the event occurred

What I want to achieve is:

- for a list of event keys eg `['event_1','event_2', 'event_3']
- get counts of the number of people that performed each event and all the event previous to that event, in order, ie:

  - the number of people who performed event_1
  - the number of people who performed event_1, and then event_2
  - the number of people who performed event_1, and then event_2, and then event_3
  - etc
- a secondary goal is to be able to get the average occurred_at date for each event so that I can calculate the average time between each event

The best I have got is the following two map reduces:

```
db.events.mapReduce(function () {
  emit(this.person_id, {
    e: [{
      e: this.event,
      o: this.occurred_at
    }]
  })
}, function (key, values) {
  return {
    e: [].concat.apply([], values.map(function (x) {
      return x.e
    }))
  }
}, {
  query: {
    account_id: ObjectId('52011239b1b9229f92000003'),
    event: {
      $in: ['event_a', 'event_b', 'event_c','event_d','event_e','event_f']
    }
  },
  out: 'people_funnel_chains',
  sort: { person_id: 1, occurred_at: 1 }
})
```

And then:

```
db.people_funnel_chains.mapReduce(function() {
  funnel = ['event_a', 'event_b', 'event_c','event_d','event_e','event_f']
  events = this.value.e;
  for (var e in funnel) {
    e = funnel[e];
    if ((i = events.map(function (x) {
      return x.e
    }).indexOf(e)) > -1) {
      emit(e, { c: 1, o: events[i].o })
      events = events.slice(i + 1, events.length);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}, function(key,values) {
    return {
        c: Array.sum(values.map(function(x) { return x.c })),
        o: new Date(Array.sum(values.map(function(x) { return x.o.getTime() }))/values.length)
    };
}, { out: {inline: 1} })
```

I would like to achieve this is in real time using the aggregate framework but can see no way to do it. For 10s of thousands of records this is taking 10s of seconds, I can run it incrementally which means its fast enough for new data coming in but if I want to modify the original query (eg change the event chain) it can't be done in a single request which I would love it to be able to do.

### Update using Cursor.forEach()

Using Cursor.forEach() I've managed to get huge improvement on this (essentially removing the requirement for the first map reduce).

```
var time = new Date().getTime(), funnel_event_keys = ['event_a', 'event_b', 'event_c','event_d','event_e','event_f'], looking_for_i = 0, looking_for = funnel_event_keys[0], funnel = {}, last_person_id = null;
for (var i in funnel_event_keys) { funnel[funnel_event_keys[i]] = [0,null] };
db.events.find({
  account_id: ObjectId('52011239b1b9229f92000003'),
  event: {
    $in: funnel_event_keys
  }
}, { person_id: 1, event: 1, occurred_at: 1 }).sort({ person_id: 1, occurred_at: 1 }).forEach(function(e) {

  var current_person_id = e['person_id'].str; 

  if (last_person_id != current_person_id) {
    looking_for_i = 0;
    looking_for = funnel_event_keys[0]
  }

  if (e['event'] == looking_for) {
    var funnel_event = funnel[looking_for]
    funnel_event[0] = funnel_event[0] + 1;
    funnel_event[1] = ((funnel_event[1] || e['occurred_at'].getTime()) + e['occurred_at'].getTime())/2;
    looking_for_i = looking_for_i + 1;
    looking_for = funnel_event_keys[looking_for_i]
  }

  last_person_id = current_person_id;
})
funnel;
new Date().getTime() - time;
```

I wonder if something custom with data in memory would be able to improve on this? Getting 100s of thousands of records out of MongoDB into memory (on a different machine) is going to be a bottle neck, is there a technology I'm not aware of that could do this?

Comment: This is one of the few cases with aggregation framework is not helpful, I cannot even see this happening in realtime to be honest, it is really hard for a database to do this efficiently

Comment: This might be best solved by implementing something custom (your own in-memory analysis engine), or looking to other database options.

Comment: The solution I'm actually working with at the minute is ordering events by person_id and occurred_at (with index) and then iterating over with Cursor.forEach(). it can reduce 25k peoples 362k events in about 4s on my MPB waaay faster than the 50+s it takes with the map reduce listed above. I wonder if something custom would be able to improve on this as getting 100s of thousands of records out of MongoDB into memory is always going to be a bottle neck, is there a technology I'm not aware of that could do this?

Comment: Does each event occur multiple times for each person?  Are you only interested in first event when you say "in order"?  I think this can be done with aggregation framework, actually, at least some/most of it - you might need two aggregation framework queries...

Comment: @msaspence So this looks quite straight forward with a single aggregation pipeline.  I'm not 100% clear on how you mean average time - I can show an example which calculates average time between actions.

Comment: Btw, I ran my example on 40,000 document collection and it takes about 200ms

Answer (score 3):

I wrote up a [complete answer on my MongoDB blog](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/10/aggregating-over-time.html) but as a summary, what you have to do is project your actions based on which ones you care about to map values of action field into appropriate key names, group by person aggregating for the three actions when they did them (and optionally how many times) and then project new fields which check if action2 was done after action1, and action3 was done after action2...  Last phase just sums up the number of people who did just 1, or 1 and then 2, or 1 and then 2 and then 3.

Using a function to generate the aggregation pipeline, it's possible to generate results based on array of actions passed in.

In my test case, the entire pipeline ran in under 200ms for a collection of 40,000 documents (this was on my small laptop).

As it was correctly pointed out, the general solution I describe assumes that while an actor can take any action multiple times that they can only advance from action1 to action2 but that they cannot skip directly from action1 to action3 (interpreting action order as describing prerequisites where you cannot do action3 until you've done action2).

As it turns out, aggregation framework can be used even for sequences of events where the order is completely arbitrary but you still want to know how many people at some point did the sequence action1, action2, action3.

The main adjustment to make on the original answer is to add an extra two-stage step in the middle.  This step unwinds the collected by person document to re-group it finding the first occurrence of the second action that comes *after* the first occurrence of the first action.

Once we have that the final comparison becomes for action1, followed by earliest occurrence of action2 and compare that to the latest occurrence of action3.

It can probably be generalized to handle arbitrary number of events but every additional event past two would add two more stages to the aggregation.

Here is [my write-up of the modification of the pipeline](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/10/more-on-aggregations-over-time.html) to achieve the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Correct my if I'm wrong but this solution will only work if the first instances of each event are in the order you want? EG if you were looking for the sequence e1, e2, e3 and had the someone had triggered the following sequence: e1, e3, e2, e3 it would only register as them having got to . If you can make the assumption the e3 cannot be fired until e2 has been this is fine, unfortunately we cannot make that assumption.

Comment: it wasn't clear to me whether each action can be done multiple times and whether you cared about each action being done in strict order - originally I had both first and last times for each action to use in a more complex comparison.

Comment: if you clarify your exact requirements I can explain how you can adjust the algorithm.  If you keep first and last times you can compare first time of action to last time of next action - do you consider that something like e2, e1, e3, e2, e1, e2 does *not* satisfy your requirement?  and e1, e3, e2, e3, e1, e3, e2, e1, e3 does?  The pipeline would be slightly more complicated, but it's still doable (though it would be less generalizable to arbitrary sequences of actions passed in - current variant works for any number of actions greater than or equal to one.

Comment: By the way, your example of e1,e3,e2,e3 only should be considered if there is no concept of doing things "out of order".  If you elaborate on what the action represent, it might help - the specific example I had applied this technique to specifically cared about "last action before another action" type sequences, which isn't the case for you it seems.

Comment: For us we cannot make any assumptions about what order or how many times each event is triggered as they are given to us by third parties. I can imagine a lot of cases where that is not the case, but for us unfortunately it is. Seeing your write up did make me think what about doing the comparison based on the first AND last but for each variation of this idea that I tried could come up with always had false positives or false negatives. You are correct e2, e1, e3, e2, e1, e2 does not satisfy the requirement and e1, e3, e2, e3, e1, e3, e2, e1, e3

Comment: ok, but we agree that this is easily done with only two events, right? (check if earliest event1 comes before latest event2?)  I think I can do this for three events in agg framework, just not arbitrary number of events.

Comment: Okay, I have an answer for you - you can do it, it actually runs faster than the generalized "ordered" answer.  I'll write it up on my blog in detail but I'll add a comment to my answer here showing what the extra steps in the middle need to be.