# Is Hadoop a good solution for small data?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

We have a set of data in MongoDB that we are map reducing (twice) we're going to be using Mongo's map reduce for now, but I'm thinking about how to scale and improve performance in the future and am thinking about Hadoop.

Most of the stuff I'm reading about Hadoop talks about big data, terabytes of the stuff, when we're going to be dealing with megabytes, 10s maybe 100s of thousands of records. (There may be many of these running concurrently though so whilst a single task is small total could be large).

We really want to get insane performance out of small data rather than make it possible to do big data. i.e. get map reduce results that take 10s of seconds in MongoDB to take seconds or sub second in Hadoop.

Is this possible?
Is Hadoop a good fit for this?
If not what other technologies are there that will make this possible?

Details of exact problem this is needed for and my solution to date, can be found in this question: [Linear funnel from a collection of events with MongoDB aggregation, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793035/linear-funnel-from-a-collection-of-events-with-mongodb-aggregation-is-it-possib)

Comment: I'm not going to answer the question as I don't know Hadoop, but reading the answers to this question and the linked question, I wonder whether, considering the size of the data involved, you might get a better solution out of a custom application that stores the data in memory. The computations weren't the same style, but I have had a similar need: maximum speed. The only solution we found was more RAM!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is this possible?**

NO. No matter how small your data is there will always be some initial delay while running MR jobs, incurred because a lot of things happening under the hood, like checking input/output paths, split creation, map creation etc. And this is unavoidable.

**Is Hadoop a good fit for this?**

NO. You can't expect Hadoop to give you results in nano or a few milliseconds.

**If not what other technologies are there that will make this possible?**

If you need something really fast and which scales well better have a look at **[Storm](http://storm-project.net/)**.

Comment: When I say sub second, I mean just under. If we can get results in under 3s it'll be a big win.

Comment: 3s is still too low..

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the stuff I'm reading about Hadoop talks about big data, terabytes of the stuff, when we're going to be dealing with megabytes, 10s maybe 100s of thousands of records.

One of the things that gives hadoop its speed is its clustering abilities with Map Reduce, such things, of course, only really apply to "Big Data" (whatever that means now-a-days).

In fact map reduce is normally slower than say, the aggregation framework on small data because of how long it takes to actually run an average map reduce.

Map reduce is really designed for something other than what your doing.

You could look into storing your data in a traditional database and use that databases aggregation framework, i.e. SQL or MongoDB.

Comment: Map reduce has been the only way I've been able to do the logic I need, the complicating factor is the order in which the records (in this case events) occurred. Not something I've had to do before nor something I can find any body else writing about (which isnt to say they aren't). Its stored in mongo and try as I might I've failed to get the logic in to the aggregation framework. Details of the original problem are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793035/linear-funnel-from-a-collection-of-events-with-mongodb-aggregation-is-it-possib

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not going to fulfill your requirements. The very first things is infrastructure requirement and its administration. The cost of running map-reduce will be more on hadoop than in Mongo or other similar technologies if your data is in MBs.

Furthermore, I'd like to suggest to expand your existing mongoDB infrastructure. The querying and document based flexibilities (like easy indexes and data retrieval ) cannot be achieved with Hadoop technologies easily.

Comment: Since my problem with MongoDB is straight line speed (MongoDBs map reduce not being distributed) expanding MongoDB infrastructure isn't going to help.

Comment: Additionally as edited above, data for any one job will be small but there may be many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop 'in general' is moving toward lower latency processing, through projects like [Tez](http://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-tez-faster-hadoop-processing/) for instance. And there are hadoop-like alternatives, like [Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/).

But for event processing, and usually that means Storm, the future may already be here, see [Storm and Hadoop: Convergence of Big-Data and Low-Latency Processing](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/storm-hadoop-convergence-big-data-low-latency-processing-54503.html) (also see the [slideshare from Hadoop Summit](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/feng-june26-1120amhall1v2)).

Hadoop is a vast ecosystem. There are huge differences in capabilities between the old (1.0), the new (1.3) and the bleeding edge (2.0 and beyond). Can some of these technologies replace Mongo's own M/R? I certainly think so. Can your problem be split out into many parallel tasks (this is actually not clear to me)? Then somewhere between Spark/YARN/Tez there is a solution that would go *faster* as you throw more hardware at it.

And of course, for a workset that first in one host RAM there will always be a SMP RDBMS that will run circles around clusters...